# Insert ERROR - mysql connector python 2.7

Tags: python, sql-insert, mysql-connector

I am attempting to insert some sentiment analysis results (google cloud language API) into a mysql database. I am using the [mysql connector](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-cursor-transaction.html).

```
import mysql.connector
from google.cloud import language

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='blahuser', password='Blahpw',
                          host='BlahIP',
                          database='FeedbackDB')

cursor = cnx.cursor(buffered=True)
CoreSQL = ("SELECT ResID, TextResp FROM Response")
cursor.execute(CoreSQL)
client = language.Client()

for row in cursor:
    document = client.document_from_text(row[1])
    sent_analysis = document.analyze_sentiment()
    sentiment = sent_analysis.sentiment
    annotations = document.annotate_text(include_sentiment=True, include_syntax=True, include_entities=True)
    print(row[0], sentiment.score, sentiment.magnitude)
    ResID_ =row[0]
    PhraseSent_ = sentiment.score
    PhraseMag_ = sentiment.magnitude
    SQLInsertCmd = ("INSERT INTO PhraseAnalysis (ResID, PhraseSent, PhraseMag),  VALUES (%s,%s,%s)");
    cursor.execute(SQLInsertCmd, (ResID_, PhraseSent_,PhraseMag_))

cnx.commit()
cursor.close()
cnx.close()
```

The error I get indicates I have an issue with my INSERT statement :

> `python tm16.py
>   (1, -0.4, 2.2)
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "tm16.py", line 27, in <module>
>       cursor.execute(SQLInsertCmd, (ResID_, PhraseSent_,PhraseMag_))
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 559, in execute
>       self._handle_result(self._connection.cmd_query(stmt))
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 494, in cmd_query
>       result = self._handle_result(self._send_cmd(ServerCmd.QUERY, query))
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 396, in _handle_result
>       raise errors.get_exception(packet)
>   mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '  VALUES (1,-0.4,2.2)' at line        1`

There are lots of INSERT examples online, but I haven't be able to resolve. New to coding- no doubt something simple. Can someone point out where I am going wrong?

Mike

Comment: (ResID, PhraseSent, PhraseMag),  <-- comma

Comment: Thanks - comma removed, and INSERT works. However it appears there is also an issue with the loop. Only one row of records (the first iteration of the loop) is being inserted (1, -0.4, 2.2), however there should be 3 rows insert (1, -0.4, 2.2), (2, -0.6, 2.4), (3, 0.1, 2.4). Ideas?

Comment: Did you consider the possibility that there may be only one row in that table you are querying

Comment: Definitely 3 rows. But I will mark this as answered, and treat the single vs multiple rows question as a separate question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an unnecessary comma after the end of the fields list.